# Building a parachain node exceeds the 14GB disk limit on github actions free tier

Tags: build, cicd, slow

The compile time problems with Substrate are well known. But recently I hit a new issue: Building a simple parachain node and its test harness takes more than 14GB.

While 14GB may seem like an arbitrary bar to set, this is a real practical threshold, because it is the space available to github action free runners. These runners are the defacto standard for almost every exploration project when a new dev explores the ecosystem.

This needs a serious fix. I try to make improvements to Substrate's dependency graph ((example)[https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/1897]), and also provided workarounds when necessary ((example)[https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/2553]). And I hope that the community will all do their part as well.

But in the meantime, **what practical workarounds are there?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building with the `--release` flag is enough to make it work. It takes more time, and more carbon footprint though.